# Convert Xcode view hierarchy RGB color

Tags: xcode, rgb

How can I convert this to RGB 0-255 values?

[image]

Comment: Where exactly do you see that color? Normally you just multiply the components by `255`.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, it's in the 3d view debugging (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) after clicking on a label. Multiplying with 255 doesn't seem to find the correct result.

Comment: Multiplying by 255 does yield the correct result. `UIColor` represents color components as floating point values in the 0-1 range. Multiplying them by 255 is enough to get them to the 0-255 range. In this case `0, 122, 255,` or `007AFF`.
By the way, this is the default tint color [UIColor.systemBlue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3173141-systemblue)

Comment: @Sulthan sorry, you are correct. Thanks for your comment.